# How can I find which activities or services I can use from another program

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have great experience in java programming but new to android programming. 
If I want to use activities or services of other programs, how can I find out how to do it?
I tried to extract and read the metafile from an apk. But it was no real success.
Do I have to ask the author or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Ask author is the best way (or read documentation). Because without knowing what extras you should send to Activity (or at least, why do you need that Activity), there is no point in such access.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenIntents](http://www.openintents.org/en/) is a great place to check which intents are available for you to use from your apps.  It gives a kind of 'open access' list of intents, which should be freely available for you to use *as long* as the user has those apps on their system.  In practice this might be a little hard to enforce, but you can always [check if the intent will succeed](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html), and do something else if the user doesn't have the proper app installed.

Comment: Unfortunally "check if ...! is a dangling link. But thank you anyway

Comment: really?  Worked for me?  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html